# (C++) How can I access the 2 other diagonals above and below the first diagonal?

Tags: c++, matrix

Specification: first diagonal = diagonal that goes from the very top left corner to the very bottom right corner.

Take a matrix where:

> (1) is the diagonal that goes from the top left corner to the bottom right corner,

> (2) are the elements under(and above) the diagonal (therefore being the other 2 diagonals surrounding the first diagonal)

> (0) every other element from the matrix

So the matrix would end up like this:

```
1  2  3  3

2  1  2  3

3  2  1  2

3  3  2  1
```

My question is, how can I access the elements marked with (2) from the matrix?

Comment: What does "access" mean?

Comment: If every index on a diagonal has the property `x == y`, what would the properties be for indices for items above and below that diagonal?

Comment: Hi Dr21, the purpose of stack overflow is to create a base knowledge about practical issues that may be found in a developer's daily activities. Let's say here you'll not find an answer to students' homework or how to create a website, here you'll find help on nitty-gritty details of a language, answers on unexpected program behaviors, people willing to share their knowledge on specific issues. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: access as in a condition that drives you to that specific place (in this case, the (2) "subdiagonals") and manipulate them (as in modify the value from, let's say, 5 to 10)

Comment: @dr21, you are more than welcome to post a question, simply try to stick with the purpose of this great developers 2 developers service

Answer (score 0):

For the diagonal "below" you can do something like

```
for (int i = 1; i < colums; ++i){
    std::cout << matrix[i][i-1] << std::endl;
}
```

and for the one "above"

```
for (int i = 0; i < colums - 1; ++i){
    std::cout << matrix[i][i+1] << std::endl;
}
```

please note that this will only work for square matrices, if you don't have a square matrix the number of columns and rows is not the same so you need to set up a different loop that accounts for this case.

You could do something along these lines, even if I don't really like having `for` loops with more than one variable and i think it's hard to understand at first glance.

You sdould clean it up a bit and make it more error resistant before using it but it illustrates the idea

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < columns && j < rows; ++i, ++j){
    std::cout << matrix[i][j] << std::endl;
}
```

Having `i` and `j` start from `0` will give you the "main diagonal", having `i` start from `1` and `j` from `0` will give you the one "below" and having `i` start from `0` and `j` from `1` will give you the one "above"

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any type of matrix assuming the main diagonal as elements with (i == j).

```
#include <iostream>
#define size [10][10] // assuming the max size of matrix to be 10 * 10

int main() {
    int m = 0, n = 0;
    std::cin >> m >> n; // reading number of rows in m and cols in n
    int arr[m][n] = {0}; 
    // to accept matrix elements
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) std::cin >> arr[i][j];
    // to print diagonal above the main diagonal
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if (i == j && j != n - 1) std::cout << arr[i][j + 1] << '\n';
    // to print diagonal below the main diagonal
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if (i == j && i != 0) std::cout << arr[i][j - 1] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```